# Can a button have a border when disabled?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

The mouse is hidden on the screen so the only way the user knows where to scroll is since the buttons have a border when the mouse enters them.
When you click on a button the button becomes disabled, but the border disappears

Is there a way to make a button have a border color even when it is disabled?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your situation.  Besides clarifying your question, please add the appropriate tag: WinForms, WPF, etc.

Comment: When a button is disabled it has a "greyed-out" look, is it possible to add a border to that button?

Comment: But your question is also talking about scrolling and disabling it when clicking on it, etc.  Maybe a screen shot would help because I can't figure out why a disabled button would need an active border.

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes (specially not for "unclear what you are asking"). The question is perfectly clear... the end result and the usability might be weird, but the question: `is there a way to make a button have a border color even when it is disabled?` is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you're trying to solve a different problem that you should :D Why is mouse hidden?

But, to answer the question: you could store in codebehind bools for each button, and in click-handler check them for being true/false (and if false, then just return instead of executing normal click actions). You can also from codebehind for example change text colour to grey or something to simulate disabling the button.

Comment: The mouse is hidden on purpose, my question is: Is it possible to have a button border when button is disabled?

Comment: Not that I know of - disabling a button applies specific styling to it. But you can disable its functionality with those bools :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to custom-draw the button (which could be an option), you could just put the button inside a `Panel`, with `Dock` on the button set to `Fill`, and have the panel's `Padding` set to the border thickness you want.

Then you only have to change the panel's `BackColor` to set the fake-border (and use the `Panel`'s position and size settings to actually set the button).

You could easily make a user control out of this if you are going to use it many times

Sample:

[image]

Here's the [Designer.cs](http://pastebin.com/g0VqFs4U) source code for the screenshot (**update**: I saw the question is tagged for vb.net, but the `Designer.cs` file was created using the designer... you don't "need" this code, I put it just as a reference of how the screenshot was created)

As a side note, I agree with the rest: this is "generally" a UX disaster (having an "active border" on a disabled button), however, I do not know your desired end result nor know your application/requirements, so I'm just telling a way that it could easily be done. I am not definitely implying that it *should* be done.